# Migration from 1.9 to 2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento2.2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I am having a bit of a brain fart here.

I am trying to migrate from 1.9.3.7 to 2.2.6

I have attempted to perform this migration before, and the deltas screwed me up. So now, I have migrated the 1.9 from the old hosting provider to AWS where I can manage the full stack. I then have a new server running as a development server that hosts a 1.9 instance and a 2.2.5 instance.

For whatever reason, I can't seem to process how this is supposed to work with production data.

I feel like I am over thinking it. I was thinking that I needed to have an RO DB but if I did that, then the migration tool would not work to create new tables in the database for the migration, but I also don't want to touch the production data, so I don't want the migration tool touching the old server. But then I feel like I want a 1-way sync from the prod DB to the dev DB, but will it get screwed up with new orders/customers from the prod DB after the sync has been performed?

Any suggestions on what I am missing? I feel like it is just something simple.

Thanks.

Comment: Make a copy of your 1.9 instance, DB and all, and run the migration tool from the copied instance to the new m2 instance

Comment: So the 1.9 instance on the new server is a mirror of the prod site, just a little outdated on the DB side.

So how do you manage the "threat" of new information from order and customers?

Comment: Ok. So run your migration tool land when you have it working perfectly you'll be ready to run it off the live 1.9 database on final push to production